# How to place ion-avatar top-left of an ion-item?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

[image]
I have an ion-item with ion-avatar and ion-label with large text.
For showing full text in ion-label i added a class 'ion-text-nowrap' to ion-label.
It works fine.
But the problem is ion-avatar automatically placed to vertical center of ion-item.
I don't need to align avatar vertical align middle. I want that align left-top of ion-item. How can i do that?

This is my code:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-avatar slot="start">
    <img [src]="img">
  </ion-avatar>
  <ion-label class="ion-text-nowrap">
    <p>{{text}}</p>
  </ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the `problem`?

Comment: edited question with screenshot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no css properties to achieve this in Ionic.
But it is possible by overwriting the css of the `ion-avatar` and `ion-label`.

Change the position of the avatar to `absolute` and place it in the top corner of the item. Then adjust the label margin to place the text back where you want it.

```
ion-avatar{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

ion-label{
  margin-left: // size needed
}
```

---

Example output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the perfect solution!
Add the `ion-align-self-stretch` class to the `ion-avatar`!

My example:

```html
<ion-item>
  <ion-icon class="ion-align-self-stretch" name="text-outline" slot="start"></ion-icon>
  <ion-textarea
    [autoGrow]="true"
    formControlName="description"
    label="Beschreibung"
    rows="1"
  ></ion-textarea>
</ion-item>
```

[image]